# How to configure authorize.net payment processor to use another currency

Tags: civicontribute, authorize.net, currency

Authorize.net itself boosts it supports multiple currencies:
https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/The-Authorize-Net-Developer-Blog/Authorize-Net-Expansion-into-Canada-the-United-Kingdom-and/ba-p/33690

The list of payment processors shows a 'blank' when it comes to regional support for the Authorize.net payment processor:
https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Payment+Processors

Elsewhere on stackexchange, someone explains how to support other currencies
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16014643/does-authorize-net-support-different-currency-types/16031041#16031041

Could that apply to CiviCRM too ? Is it just not implemented yet ?

Somehow, we always use US$. The message above says

> If you’re not sending the currency code, or if you’re using any of our
>   other Authorize.Net APIs, no changes are required at this time. The
>   currency code for those APIs will automatically default to the
>   currency associated with the merchant’s processor.

What does that mean - could we change the option to euro at the merchant interface ?

Comment: Are you sure they are saying 'multiple currencies on one interface' or that hey they actually now know that the UK and Euro exist? I was looking in to this only today, but actually was hitting the issue of a.net settings not allowing for out of USA countries to be making contributions

Comment: @petednz-fuzion I am sure contributions from other countries are allowed, but only in US$ on my installation

Comment: Have you set Euro as the currency on your site as per the answer below?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the API call and/or payment form in CiviCRM would need modification to handle say, USD -OR- Euros -OR- GBP, is that right? Seeing that no further answers were given since Feb 2017.  And in Authorize, the payments might have to go to different accounts?

Comment: Yes, as far as I know now, CiviCRM supports one currency per contribution page. At the very least, you'll have to configure different pages for each currency. Also, there is a problem displaying the currency sign - this seems a bug.

Comment: For Auth.net, they have confirmed you need different accounts to support different currencies. Also, you are only able to get an account to support f.e. euros if your company is registered in certain countries - this is not a technical issue, but a requirement of their merchant account providers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change your default currency in Civi to see if that fixes your problem? It is under Administer > Localization

Comment: I haven't, because I was actually looking for a way to support multiple currencies with authorize.net